# How to do a task scheduling in python?

Tags: python-2.7

I have a python application which is used fetch data from one database to another database. I want to schedule this process in a daily basis. How to implement this?

Comment: Not sure which OS you are working on , but there are task schedulers in almost all the OS which you can use to link your python application, that does the job.

Comment: I am using ubuntu 14.04. can you please guide me how to do that in ubuntu 14.04